# COPY failed: no source files were specified

Tags: gradle, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Error while building gitlab ci.
Maybe I need to change the path of COPY, but I'm not sure.

Project structure
[image]

Dockerfile

```
FROM gradle:7.4-jdk17 as builder
WORKDIR /build

# 그래들 파일이 변경되었을 때만 새롭게 의존패키지 다운로드 받게함.
COPY build.gradle settings.gradle /build/
RUN gradle build -x test --parallel --continue > /dev/null 2>&1 || true

# 빌더 이미지에서 애플리케이션 빌드
COPY . /build
RUN gradle clean build --status

# APP
FROM openjdk:17.0-slim
WORKDIR /app

# 빌더 이미지에서 jar 파일만 복사
COPY --from=builder ./trainerd-api/build/libs/*-SNAPSHOT.jar ./app.jar

EXPOSE 8080

# root 대신 nobody 권한으로 실행
USER nobody
ENTRYPOINT [                                                \
    "java",                                                 \
    "-jar",                                                 \
    "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom",              \
    "-Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=0",                             \
    "app.jar"              \
]
```

Error in Jobs

step 9/12 success and push my container repository

Comment: It's possible that your wildcard expands to nothing. Check that path exists.